# Mapbox boundaries error "402 - Payment required"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

```
map.addSource('pos-4', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.boundaries-pos4-v3',
})
```

Using Mapbox GL, this code throws an error when requesting the Mapbox API.

> { status: 402, message: "Payment required" }

This has been working for the past two weeks, and only started throwing this error today. On the Mapbox admin console it shows no outstanding billing issues or any other errors. How has this been working for so long without payment, if that is even the issue?

Comment: I can also recommend to contact the technical support of Mapbox. They will be able to tell you why this request is returning the 402 status code!

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to use the Mapbox paid tileset, [Boundaries v3](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-boundaries-v3/). You can find out more about the tileset [here](https://www.mapbox.com/boundaries/), but this tileset requires an agreement with our [Mapbox Sales team](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/sales/), and cannot be activated in your account without it.